# How to wake up Zebra Bluetooth Printer programmatically after the inactivity timeout?

Tags: xamarin.forms, zebra-printers, visual-studio-mac

I am using Xamarin to build a mobile app that will print out the label via connected Bluetooth device (ZQ320). After the inactivity timeout, the connection seems like broken when I wake up the ZQ320 with long press the power button on the device. It is really frustrated that I need to rebuild the connection again and wait for few minutes. My question is how can I wake up the ZQ320 programmatically and resume the previous connection so that I can continue printing without rebuilding the connection between the mobile and the printer? Appreciate for any comment.

Comment: You might have to check if the printer allows it to be done, check their documentation with regards to this may be.

Answer (score 0):

The ZQ320 does support sleep mode. If you ensure that the printer goes to sleep rather than turning off then you should be able to wake it by sending data. See this document for more information:

https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/software/en/application-notes/AppNote-SleepMode-v5.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Simple, just make the printer never sleep.